# SharePoint WSP deployment does not complete, because SharePoint update

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, wsp

I've access to SharePoint Production Farm Frontend two Servers which don't have Central Admin, I deployed WSP there many times using Add-SPSolution & Install-SPSolution, last time I used Uninstall-SPSolution & Remove-SPSolution to retract and remove WSP and redeploying it again, because I added new feature in the solution.
The problem is, the deploying is stuck and don't complete, as I know after that from Fram's Administrator, a new update has been installed on the Farm and interrupted it.

So, if I replaced my solution dll file in GAC, I copied .ascx files to CONTROLTEMPLATES in 16 hive folder and I created Feature.xml file in FEATURES folder in 16 hive, is the deployment will be done by doing these steps?
I need to do deployment without using PowerShell commands, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Manual Deployment Steps:

1- Copy a new featuer folder to Features folder in 16 Hive

2- Copy ascx folder to CONTROLTEMPLATE folder in 16 Hive.

3- Run this command Install-SPFeature -path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\FeatuerFolderName" -Force

4- In WebApp config file mark your web part as SafeControl.

5- Change the solution dll file name in GAC and copy and past the new dll file.